# How to create a recommendation algorithm ("If you like X and Y, you might like Z")?

Tags: algorithms

How to create a recommendation algorithm ("If you like X and Y, you might like Z")?

I want to create an algorithm which recommends "You might also like" items from an itemlist, based on user's current liked itemlist (favorites) and based on those created by other users with similar preferences (in JS/MySQL, but that should not be of importance).

The input is simply a set of all items, and subsets (list of favorites) created by users.

Update: @Robert Harvy's Music example is a good one for clarification. Itemset: 100 bands. John likes bands 1,2,3,4,5, 11,12. Jane likes 1,2,3,4,5, 10,12. Their music tastes are likely to be similar, just as their fav lists are. The algorithm should notice this and recommend band 10 to John and 11 to Jane. No characteristics would need to be concidered in this simple scenario.

Comment: Simple: your run Amazon and gather statistical data from their visitor logs. ;-)

Comment: @Doc Brown I don't think visitor logs have has anything to do with my question. I need to create a "you might like" lists as subsets of an itemlist based on current favourites lists.

Comment: Is this a request for code?  Coding questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Not really, an approach or possibly an existing solution is what I'm after. If I wanted code, I'd go Stack Overflow, but the question as such is "too broad" for SO.

Comment: I don't see what is too broad about this question.  It has a pretty straightforward (basic) answer: find all the other people who like X and Z, build a histogram of their favorites and suggest one or more with the highest frequency.

Comment: Could you pls be more specific, with the music example in mind (see question update), and maybe post is as an answer?

Comment: @JimmyJames: well, after the edit, the question does not look so broad to me any more. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Marko36: ok, not visitors logs, I meant buyers logs, since they indicate items people "like". You will probably need a huge data basis to make a statistical approach work well.

Answer (score 1):

You find similarities between objects by identifying characteristics of those objects and then see which characteristics two or more objects have in common.  Or, you simply watch the behavior of online customers and compare what they buy with other things they also buy.

For example, if you Google "Bands Like Steely Dan," Google will respond with the Doobie Brothers, Steve Winwood, the Allman Brothers Band, Eagles, Fleetwood Mac, Jackson Browne, Talking Heads, Eric Clapton, Crosby Stills and Nash, Hall and Oates, James Taylor, Neil Young, Simon & Garfunkel, etc.

Now, it could be credibly argued that these bands don't really resemble Steely Dan's musical style all that much.  What they do have in common is that they all come from the same era, and they are all in the "classic rock" genre.  And yes, folks who like Steely Dan also tend to like these other bands.

That's how you make a recommendation engine.  You find things to recommend that have characteristics in common with the thing that the user searched or bought.